# Can I use scala type parameters with a val?

Tags: scala, generics, types

I am going through some exercises to get accustomed to Scala's type system. I have a helper function for running unit tests where I specify the input and expected output of a function. In this case the function I'm testing returns the first n elements of a list:

```
val inputs: List[TestCase[(List[Any], Int), List[Any]]] = List(
      TestCase(
        input = (List('a', 't', 'o'), 2),
        output = List('a', 't')
      ),
      TestCase(
        input = (List("Vegetable", "Fruit"), 4),
        output = List("Vegetable", "Fruit")
      ),
      TestCase(
        input = (List(3.14, 6.22, 9.5), -7),
        output = Nil
      )
    )
```

My question is if it is possible to specify a type parameter for this **input** val. That List[Any] is alright, but I want to specify somehow that the input list has the same type of elements as the output List. Something like this (doesn't work btw):

```
val inputs[SameType]: List[TestCase[(List[SameType], Int), List[SameType]]] = ...
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Maybe type parameters are not meant to be used with vals?

In case you're wondering why I'm not just asserting the results: it's because I have multiple implementations of the same function and I don't want to repeat the test cases for every implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider parameterising your model like so

```
case class TestCase[T](input: (List[T], Int), output: List[T])
```

so now we can define, say,

```
val inputs: List[TestCase[String]] = ???
```

In Scala 2 value definition cannot be parameterised but a method definition can, for example

```
def input[T](x: List[TestCase[T]]) = ???
```

however Scala 3 might [change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60055124/5205022) that so we can write

```
val input = [T] => (x: List[TestCase[T]]) => ???
```

Another approach is to use generalised constraints, for example,

```
def assertEquals[A, B](input: List[A], output: List[B])(implicit ev: A =:= B) = ???

assertEquals(List(1), List("")) // error: Error: Cannot prove that Int =:= String
```

Consider [munit](https://github.com/scalameta/munit/blob/cb874360903d7e525acda709cfa8b3497c4ca745/munit/shared/src/main/scala/munit/Assertions.scala#L75) for examples of generalised constraints.